# How can I use the Python language to put add-ins in Excel without using Pyxll or xlwings or VBA?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, pyxll

I am trying to figure out how to use Python-based functions in excel. I came across *Pyxll* which can make Python add-ins instead of using VBA. But *Pyxll* is not free after their 30-day trial.

I also came across *xlwings* which worked fine and served the purpose of adding *udfs* in excel, the problem is--- it is not very user-friendly. I have to put the excel file in the same folder as the python file plus, they should also have the same names with different extensions. Or I may use the *xlwings* quickstart command to do that.

This means I have to create such folders everytime I wish to include my python based functions in a new excel project file and copy paste the functions from the previous python files to the newly created quickstart files.

I was wondering if there is any way to use only one python file to import user-defined functions using *xlwings* or perhaps a different library/module which is free to use and does that?

(PS: According to the *xlwings* documentation, we can point to a *udf* module under the *xlwings* tab in excel but even after many attempts I am not able to make it work )

Comment: With xlwings, you will need to set the `PYTHONPATH` to the folder of where your module is and need to add the name of the module, as you saw, to `UDF modules`. See: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#user-settings

Comment: Wow! It worked! Thanks a lot :D